# Dropzone.js Multi File Uploader Handler

Tags: javascript, php, html, dropzone.js

I recently attempted to add a server side handler for dropzone.js and followed this video as I know little to no PHP:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVEv62wKbOc

I added all the script, but when I click "View Upload" it prints out ""; } } } echo $output;" in a blank page. Also, even though the animation of the file being uploaded is successful, the file never ends up on the "uploads" folder. (It's supposed to preview all of the uploaded pictures instead, as shown in the video on 9:32 on the video)

Below is everything I added. (Not including the dropzone.js & dropzone.css files as they have no changes made) It is currently being hosted on a localhost.

parser.php:

```html
<?php

if(!empty($_FILES)){
 
 $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $dir_separator = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
 $folder = "uploads";

 $destination_path = dirname(__FILE__).$dir_separator.$folder.$dir_separator;

 $target_path = $destination_path.$_FILES['file']['name'];
 move_uploaded_file($temp, $target_path);
} ?>
```

view_upload.php:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>View Upload</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
 $folder = "uploads";

 if(is_dir($folder)){
  $handler = opendir($folder);
  $output = "";

  while($files = readdir($handler)){
   if(!is_dir($files)){
    $output .= "<img src=\"uploads/{$files}\" width='180' height='180'>";
   }
  }

 }

 echo $output; ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Snippets of my index.html:

```html
    <header>
        <!-- Uploader -->
  <link href="dropzone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="dropzone.js"></script>
 </header>
    <body>
        <div class="uploadingFiles">
            <form action="parser.php" class="dropzone"></form>
      <p><a href="view_upload.php">View Upload</a></p>
     </div>
    </body>
```

I've also noticed that when I click "View Upload" the entire script turns into a comment, I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it though.

```html
<body>

<!--?php
 $folder = "uploads";

 if(is_dir($folder)){
  $handler = opendir($folder);
  $output = "";

  while($files = readdir($handler)){
   if(!is_dir($files)){
    $output .= "<img src=\"uploads/{$files}\" width='180' height='180'-->";
   }
  }

 }

 echo $output;



</body>
```

Comment: That's a weird bug/error... are you sure there isn't anything wrong with the files? Perhaps try to upload them to the server once more, or if you're testing this locally, redo them and save them again?

How are you testing this? Online, on a hosted server? Localhost? If localhost, which server have you set up?

Comment: I'll give it a shot & delete everything to try to reinstall. I'm hosting it using Apache.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Okay so I figured out part of the problem and fixed it. The problem was that my php wasn't directly connected with Apache. The files are now being sent to the folder, but whenever I click "View Uploads" I still get the same weird message. It's fine though, I was going to delete the "View Uploads" portion anyways

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:
`$destination_path = dirname(__FILE__).$dir_separator.$folder.$dir_separator;`
to
`$destination_path = $folder.$dir_separator;`
and see if that fixes the problem

Comment: Nothing changed, I still get the output ""; } } } echo $output;" when clicking on "View Upload" & nothing shows up in the uploads folder

Comment: Well, you're lacking an ending `?>` after the `echo $output;` but that doesn't really explain the `}`s showing up. Are these exact copies of the actual files? You haven't edited anything, either here, or in the files?

Comment: Okay - I copied the files, and set up a quick test on my own server, and it works just fine. It loads the uploaded files into the "uploads" folder, and so on and so forth. Exact same files as you have here, except I fixed the missing ending `?>` in the parser.php and the view_uploads.php. So it's something on your server - read the logs, both apache and php, to see if there is anything there.

Comment: Okay, I fixed the ?> on both files, and I tried looking for any issues but found none except I inspected the output whenever I clicked view upload and it turned all of the script on view_upload.php into a comment.

Comment: <body>

<!--?php
 $folder = "uploads";

 if(is_dir($folder)){
  $handler = opendir($folder);
  $output = "";

  while($files = readdir($handler)){
   if(!is_dir($files)){
    $output .= "<img src=\"uploads/{$files}\" width='180' height='180'-->";
   }
  }

 }

 echo $output;



</body>